# Is the fee added to the cost of the transaction or subtracted from the received money?

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, transaction-fees, sending, sendtoaddress

I want to send exactly `0.00136889` bitcoin but I never sent bitcoins before, I only received.

If I send `0.0136889` to the address, will blockchain.info remove the fee from my wallet or do I need to send `0.0136889 + the fee`?

[image: send bitcoins]

Comment: oh he won't let me send until i have at least 0.0.0003551 BTC remaining after the transaction

Answer (score 2):

The fee is paid by the sender. The sender technically specifies how much money goes into the transaction from where and how much goes out of it to where. The total output value – of course – can at most be as big as the total input value, otherwise the transaction is invalid.

When you send money using a wallet software, you specify how much money you want to send. That is, you specify how much money you want to arrive at the recipient. The wallet will then add the fee to it. Your balance will go down by the money you sent plus the fee you chose.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is... BlockChain.info will deduct the amount being sent PLUS the fee **from your wallet**.

Ergo, the total amount (sent amount + fee) cannot be more than the amount you have available in your wallet.

**You do not need to add the fee to the amount being sent.**